# How do I take all values in a column and change their values

Tags: excel

There are a lot of questions on how to multiply all values by some other cell or to move all values to another cell based on some value, but what I want is to take, in the example image below:

[image]

All the values that I have selected and divide by 2. I do not want another column, I just want to change all those values in the spread sheet and divide them by 2, the values themselves should change.

I have not found an answer for this any where and I sure it is super simple. For example, in:

`base_damage_mod` selected column, 0.03 would become: 0.015.

The only way I know to do this is manually, and that's a lot of work ...

**Whats the easiest way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by writing a macro, like in the following example:

```
Sub Divide_by_2()
  For Each c In Selection:
    If c <> "" Then
      c.Value = c.Value / 2
    End If
  Next c
End Sub
```

In order to launch this, you need to select your cells (no need to copy, or press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>), and then launch the macro.

As far as the source code is concerned, this is pretty obvious, except for the `c <> ""` part: I have added this in order to avoid the value 0 being filled in in empty cells.

Is there a way to do this without VBA, without macros?
Yes, there is, but it involves you creating a new column, in there type a formula, then copy the values of that formula into again another column and remove the first two columns, in other words: it's quite Messi :-)

Answer (score 1):

If column C is empty (if not, temporarily insert a column), enter a 2  there next to every used column D item (*).
Copy all of column C, and "Paste Special" onto column D using Operation>Divide.

(*) If there are too many items to manually do the "2", copy this formula down column C `=IF(ISBLANK(D1),"",2)` and it will add them. After this, convert column C from formulas to values by copying it and using "Paste Values" to paste it back. (Special Operations won't work on formulas)

Comment: Shouldn't your formula be `=IF(ISBLANK(D1),"",D1/2)`?

Comment: If you used "Paste Special>Operation>Multiply", yes. But, it's Divide in my answer. Divide by 2, Multiply by 1/2, either is fine.